# In bash, how can I convert a Unicode Codepoint [0-9A-F] into a printable character?

Tags: bash, unicode

I have a list of Unicode codepoints, but I don't know of a "simple" way to convert these hex values into the actual characters they represent...

I've heard that *zsh* has `echo -e '\u0965'`, but I use *bash* 4.1.

Is there something as simple as the zsh method, for bash?

Comment: See also StackOverflow: **[How to convert \uXXXX unicode to UTF-8 using console tools in *nix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795702)**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use bash's echo or /bin/echo from GNU coreutils in combination with iconv:

```
echo -ne '\x09\x65' | iconv -f utf-16be
```

By default iconv converts to your locales encoding.  Perhaps more portable than relying on a specific shell or echo command is Perl.  Most any UNIX system I am aware of while have Perl available and it even have several Windows ports.

```
perl -C -e 'print chr 0x0965'
```

Most of the time when I need to do this, I'm in an editor like Vim/GVim which has built-in support.  While in insert mode, hit Ctrl-V followed by u, then type four hex characters.  If you want a character beyond U+FFFF, use a capital U and type 8 hex characters.  Vim also supports custom easy to make keymaps.  It converts a series of characters to another symbol.  For example, I have a keymap I developed called www, it converts TM to ™, (C) to ©, (R) to ®, and so on.  I also have a keymap for Klingon for when that becomes necessary.  I'm sure Emacs has something similar.  If you are in a GTK+ app which includes GVim and GNOME Terminal, you can try Control-Shift-u followed by 4 hex characters to create a Unicode character.  I'm sure KDE/Qt has something similar.

**UPDATE:** As of Bash 4.2, it seems to be a built in feature now:

```
echo $'\u0965'
```

**UPDATE:** Also, nowadays a Python example would probably be preferred to Perl. This works in both Python 2 and 3:

```
python -c 'print(u"\u0965")'
```

Comment: Thanks... the perl one in nice and terse, but it has me a bit puzzled as to how it knows to treat the value as UTF-16BE.. I guess that's what the "chr" means...

Comment: @fred that's a good point.  The Perl example is locale sensitive.  The -C enables full Unicode processing, but the example works because my locale uses a Unicode example.  If I set LANG to C, I get a warning about a wide character in print, but it still prints.  If I print `chr 0xa2` in a UTF-8 locale I get a cents sign ¢, but if I use LANG=C, I get � because it prints out the byte 0xa2 which is invalid in UTF-8.  The Vim/GVim example is semi-sensitive to the locale.  More correctly, to the file encoding.  If you started Vim in a non-UTF-8 locale, you will need to `:set encoding=utf-8`

Comment: @fred I should point out, Perl treat the value of chr as a Unicode codepoint if Perl is started in a Unicode locale like UTF-8.  A codepoint is the unique number that represents a character and is not tied to any one encoding such as UTF-16BE or UTF-8.  It converts it to the correct encoding when it prints it out.  For example, the Cuneiform Sign A is codepoint U+012000.  I can use `chr 0x12000` in Perl (assuming Unicode is active) to represent it.  In UTF-16BE, this is 0xd8, 0x08, 0xdc, and 0x00.  You character is U+0965 which just happens to be the bytes 0x09 followed by 0x65 in UTF-16BE.

Comment: @penguin359.. Thanks, one day (hopefully) I'll have a good look at perl.. It seems unfathomably cryptic, but then so did sed and regex, initially, and now it is quite easy... maybe it's a bit like vim; a steep learning curve, then plain sailing.... It's good to read your explanation... it paves the way..

Comment: I just (re-)discovered that *Steven D's* printf soultion won't handle the ASCII block of the unicode range, so your `perl` answer is now the best (for my particular requirements).. I'd previously ruled out printf (months ago), but I'd forgotten about it. Here is the queston/answer about its limits... [Why does printf report an error on all but three (ASCII-range) Unicode Codepoints](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20806/why-does-printf-report-an-error-on-all-but-three-ascii-range-unicode-codepoints)

Answer (score 14):

[Bash 4.2](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html) (released in 2011) added support for `echo -e '\u0965'`, `printf '\u0965'`, `printf %b '\u0965'` and `echo $'\u0965'` also work.

http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ:

> ```
> o   $'...', echo, and printf understand \uXXXX and \UXXXXXXXX escape sequences.
> ```

Comment: Thanks... I'm still primarily using bash 4.1.5 in Ubuntu 10.04, but it's certainly good to know that it's now available in 4.2. (+1)

Comment: +1; note that `bash 4.2.x` versions have a bug where values between `0x80` and `0xff` (`128 - 255`) - i.e., in the extended ASCII range - are NOT correctly UTF8-encoded and instead just passed through, resulting in an invalid UTF8 char that some terminals render as `?`. As of (at least) `4.3.11` this has been fixed; if `echo $'\ued'` renders `í`, then the bug is _not_ present.

Answer (score 5):

If you have GNU coreutils, try `printf`:

```
$ printf '\u0965\n'
॥
```

`echo` can do the job if your console is using UTF-8 and you have the UTF-8 encoding:

```
$ echo -e '\xE0\xA5\xA5'
```

You can find a table of Unicode to UTF-8 hex encodings here: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/.  You can convert the Unicode code points to hex using a number of scripting languages.  Here is an example using python:

```
python -c "print(unichr(int('0965', 16)).encode('utf-8').encode('hex'))"
```

The following is a Perl script that will convert arguments to the correct hex value (many unnecessary parenthesis here):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Encode;

foreach (@ARGV) {
    say unpack('H*', encode('utf8', chr(hex($_))))
}
```

For instance,

```
./uni2utf 0965
e0a5a5
```

Of course, if you have Perl or Python you could also just use those to print the characters.

Comment: Thanks.. The `echo` won't do what I want, as Codepoints are 2-byte UTF-16 Big-Endian.. but you've reminded me that there are **2** printf functions! (I thought printf could do it, and it seems that I ws invoking the wrong one)... `$(which printf)` works... Thanks for the python example.. but for this (my learning curve), I'm trying to stick as close as possible to "bash" as the only scriting language involved.. (when I'm comfortable enough with bash, I'll get stuck into Python... btw, `.encode('hex')` is one step beyond what I need.. (I thought it looked a bit busy in there :)

Comment: Yeah, the .encode('hex') was just to get the hex code that seemed to work with echo for me.  Glad that at least part of this was helpful.

Comment: I've just now seen you perl snippet.. thanks... it's good to have these various solutions tabled...  The printf one is exactly what I was looking for (a single command, as per the zsh example) ..... I may a well post my *not-using-another-scripting-language* method which works on a stream of hex data (no \u, etc)..

Comment: I particularly like the brevity of the `printf` above, but it doesnt handle values below ``\u00A0`... I've just re-discovered something I already knew (but dropped off the radar)... Here is a Question I asked about 4 months ago; [Why does printf report an error on all but three (ASCII-range) Unicode Codepoints](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20806/why-does-printf-report-an-error-on-all-but-three-ascii-range-unicode-codepoints)... So *penguin359's* `perl` solution is looking pretty good now :) .. It's a single invocaton, and I after "easy to type", so I'll give him the green-tick for `perl`

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Here is a bash way to do a single Unicode value ...(by "bash" I mean: not using any another scripting language) .. thanks to Gilles for a suggeston in this [askubuntu Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20806/why-does-printf-report-an-error-on-all-but-three-ascii-range-unicode-codepoints/20976#20976) .
According to *[this link](http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html)*: recode (Obsoletes iconv, dos2unix, unix2dos).. *Edit:* but as per the comment below, "obsoletes' may just mean "alternative"

```
      echo -n 0x0965 |recode UTF-16BE/x4..UTF-8
```

---

Here is a method to process a **raw** hex dump as input (ie. no escaped-prefixes like; \u0965, and no \x09\x65)..
`xxd` is a hex-dump utility (packaged with `vim-common`) which can revert a raw hex dump to the characters the dump represents... Unicode Codepoints are UTF-16BigEndian, which is exactly what  a Hex-dump is..
`xxd` in revert mode accepts a stream of Hex values with line breaks.which are ignored.

This script creates a UTF-16BE stream, which it then reverts to the original chars.
The last line contains the two needed commands; `xxd` and `iconv`

```
for line in \
  "Matsuo Basho (1644-1694)" \
  "  pond" \
  "  frog jumps in" \
  "  plop!"
do 
  echo "$line" |iconv -f "$(locale charmap)" -t "UTF-16BE" |xxd -ps -u 
done |
#    (---this is the **revert** code---) 
tee >(xxd -p -u -r |iconv -f "UTF-16BE") ;echo
```

Here is the output (showing the UTF-16BE hex-dump input, first).
Note; `xxd` segments its own output with a newline at 60 hex-digits...  The revert option ignores these newlines.. it ignores any/all newlines (as the aren't hex-digits)..

```
004D0061007400730075006F00200042006100730068006F002000280031
003600340034002D00310036003900340029000A
002000200070006F006E0064000A
0020002000660072006F00670020006A0075006D0070007300200069006E
000A
002000200070006C006F00700021000A

Matsuo Basho (1644-1694)
  pond
  frog jumps in
  plop!
```

Comment: Since it seems you used penguin359's information in your answer, you might consider marking his answer as correct rather than mine.

Comment: @Steven D: a noteworthy comment, but "seem" is the operative word. I've been using iconv like this for a couple of days now, which got me wondering if there is a single command. I've done similar entire-file processing in windows (C++), so I have a reasonlabe understanding of Unicode. I was really after a quick and simple `bash` method. By "bash" I mean: using the bash scripting language; not python/perl from within bash). I've added this as an answer because it may be of some value to someone reading this page. It is good one-liner for an entire file. Your `printf` is the best answer for me.

Comment: I wouldn't say recode obsoletes iconv, in fact recode is older than iconv, and these days iconv is far more commonly installed by default than recode (for example, on Linux, iconv is almost always installed because it comes with libc).

Comment: Thanks.. I was wondering about that.. That web page isn't exactly the definitive reference... so it is more of an alternative...

Answer (score 2):

Using Pattern substitution in bash version 4.2 (and higher):

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
```

as described here http://steve-parker.org/sh/tips/pattern-substitution/

```
UNICODE_HEX="U+02211"
printf ${UNICODE_HEX/U+/"\U"}
∑

UNICODE_HEX="U+03BB"
printf ${UNICODE_HEX/U+/"\U"}
λ
```

Comment: Note that, *as stated in [a previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12273/80216#67920),* this works only in bash version 4.2 (and higher). In fact, this adds fairly little to the earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the default encoding for your OS is UTF-8 (true for most current distros)
then you can use bash directly to convert any UNICODE code point:

```
echo -e "Unicode Character 'DEVANAGARI DOUBLE DANDA' (U+0965) \U0965"
```

Of course, the glyph will appear correctly only if you have the correct font.
As of bash 4.3 all code points will work correctly. And this two builtins options will also work:

```
printf "%b" "Unicode Character (U+0965) \U0965 \n"
echo $'Unicode Character (U+0965) \U0965'
```

Note that for bash 4.2 the Unicode code points from `0x80` to `0xFF` are encoded incorrectly (bash bug). To workaround this issue you must take a look at the program at [this site](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071) (also good for a deep look into the issue of converting numbers to chars.

Comment: Works for me in bash 4.3 and zsh.  Is there a bug report for bash 4.2 you can link to?

Comment: this looks to me like the correct bug: `https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-02/msg00035.html` Description: \u and \U incorrectly encode values between \u80 and \uff

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @illucent
I can now see how to script Unicode mappings in filenames.
So (for anyone who's interested), a script that can serve as a template for anyone wanting to fix some non-ascii filenames.

```
function makelist {
RUN=false
if [[ -n ${1+X} ]] ; then RUN=true; fi
local -A UNI
A=$( printf "%d\n" 0x2000 )
B=$( printf "%d\n" 0x200f )
for N in $( seq ${A} ${B} ) ; do
    V=$( printf "%04X\n" "${N}" )
    UNI["${V}"]=' '
done
A=$( printf "%d\n" 0x2010)
B=$( printf "%d\n" 0x2015)
for N in $( seq ${A} ${B} ) ; do
    V=$( printf "%04X\n" "${N}" )
    UNI["${V}"]='-'
done
local -A MORE=( [0xA1]='!' [0xBF]='?' [0x300]='' [0x301]='' [0xB4]="'" [0xAB]="(" [0xBB]=')' [0x60]="'" [0x2018]="'" [0x2019]="'" [0x201C]="'" [0x201D]="'" [0x2032]="'" [0x2035]="'" )
for N in ${!MORE[@]} ; do
    V=$( printf "%04X\n" "${N}" )
    UNI["${V}"]="${MORE[$N]}"
done
if $RUN ; then
    ECHO= ;
else
    ECHO='-n'
fi

for XX in "${!UNI[@]}" ; do
    UHEX=$( printf "U+%04X\n" 0x${XX} )
    CHR=$( printf "${UHEX/U+/\\U}" )
    printf -- "---------Search-> %s => [%s] => [%s] ----\n" "${XX}" "${CHR}" "${UNI[$XX]}"
    find * -name "*"$( printf "${UHEX/U+/\\U}" )"*" -print -exec rename $ECHO -E "s/$CHR/${UNI[$XX]}/g;" {} \;
done
```

}

But hey... it's not an armourclad script, just a quickie to get something done, so use at your own peril.

Comment: You should run your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/