# Print a character having a codepoint

Tags: bash, character-encoding, unicode

I have a list of codepoints like 0x13000, 0x1300A.
I have to print the corresponding Unicode characters from bash.
I've already tried to do it with other commands that I've found searching in the forum ([In bash, how can I convert a Unicode Codepoint [0-9A-F] into a printable character?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12273/in-bash-how-can-i-convert-a-unicode-codepoint-0-9a-f-into-a-printable-charact)), but they didn't work.

I've tried

```
echo -ne 'x13000/x130FF/' | iconv -f utf-16be
```

and, using perl on the terminal

```
perl -C -e 'print chr 0x130F0'
```

Comment: Can you show us the the command which you tried. or give some link.

Comment: edited right now

Comment: `Didn't work` means that you saw nothing, a �  (question mark) or a codepoint square ࢚ (an odd square with numbers) ? ... ... Any of this means that you lack the required font, or that your console is failing to show the glyph (character image).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does it in two steps:

```
$ printf "$(printf '\\U%08x' 0x13000)\n"
```

If you are unable to see the rendered glyph (character image), here is a fixed image:

[image]

The two steps are:
 - The first formats the codepoint number (0x13000) in 8 hexadecimal digits with `\U` in its front.
 - The second use the bash builtin printf capacity to print Unicode characters.

The output will be adapted to the locale used.

In utf8 locales like `en_US.utf8` and with a font that could present the correct glyph, the output character will be correctly presented in the console.

In this system, the full noto-font package was installed. It contains very nice text fonts, well hinted, and as a plus it also contains glyphs for many many languages, including the "Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs" font.

This will print all the character list:

```
$ printf "$(printf '\\U%08x' 778{24..34})"; echo
```

the value range is just the hexadecimal values in decimal:

```
$ printf '%d\n' 0x13000 0x1300A
77824
77834
```

Comment: In `zsh` or `ksh93`, you could also do: `printf "$(printf '\\U%08x' {$((0x13000))..$((0x1300A))})"`

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`, to output the character in the locale charset:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -le 'print chr($_) for 0x13000 .. 0x130ff'
```

For some charsets (not UTF-8), I've seen `perl` getting it wrong. Alternatively, you could do:

```
perl -e 'print pack("L>2", $_, 10) for 0x13000 .. 0x130FF' |
  iconv -f UCS-4BE
```

to have the system's `iconv` do the translation (in the case of those Egyptian hieroglyphs, I don't expect many charsets beyond UTF-8 would support them anyway). That would be equivalent to what `zsh`/`bash` for their `$'\UXXXXXXXX'`.

To output them in UTF-8 regardless of the locale charset:

```
perl -CO -le 'print chr($_) for 0x13000 .. 0x130ff'
```

Your

```
perl -C -le 'print chr 0x130F0'
```

would work as long as the locale's charset is UTF-8 (check the output of `locale charmap`).

It would output the character. Now, you also need a font with that  [EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH E026](https://codepoints.net/U+130F0?lang=en) character, and your terminal emulator configured to use that font if you want it to be displayed there.

On Debian and derivatives, look at the `fonts-ancient-scripts` package.

Comment: The package noto-fonts (a Google font released as OFL (open)), which is a very nice text font, also contains the "Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs". It is a very useful package to install.