# Bash convert \xC3\x89 to É?

Tags: character-encoding, escape-characters, conversion

I'm running `iwlist wlo1 scan | grep ESSID` inside a script.

It displays French characters in the following format

`\xC3\x89` for É and `\xC3\xA9` for é.

I'm not sure what this format is called. I tried using an [answer for converting unicode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12279/16792) `echo -ne '\xC3\xA9' | iconv -f utf-16be` but it converted to `쎩`.

What is the official name for this format and how can I convert it in bash?

Comment: `echo -ne "\xC3\x89"` gives `É`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thank you, that fixes my issue.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest do you want to post as an answer?

Comment: Philip Kirkbride, ok, posted ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hexdecimal numeric constants are usually represented with `0x` prefix.
Character and string constants may express character codes in hexadecimal with the prefix `\x` followed by two hex digits.

`echo -ne '\xC3\x89'` should give you `É`.

- `-e` - enable interpretation of backslash escapes(including `\xHH` - byte with hexadecimal value `HH` (1 to 2 digits))

---

To deal with ***better portability*** use `printf` function:

```
printf "%b" '\xC3\x89'
É
```

Comment: `echo -e` is nonportable -- even bash doesn't always offer it, since when both `posix` and `xpg_echo` options are enabled `echo -e` just prints `-e` on output, as standard compliance requires. Better to use `printf '%b\n' '\xC3\x89'`

Comment: ...to demonstrate this, consider `bash -c 'set -o posix; shopt -s xpg_echo; printf "%b\n" "$1"; echo -e "$1"' _ '\xC3\x89'` (and note that `xpg_echo` can be set on-by-default at compile time).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you have my update

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 % echo -n éÉ | hd
 00000000  c3 a9 c3 89                                       |....|
 00000004
```

where `hd` is the hexdump utility.

So your thing is just [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding (and your observed output `\xC3\x89` is the hexadecimal representation of UTF-8). Today we have [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

My environment has both `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` (even if I am French).

Also,

```
echo '\xC3\x89\xC3\xA9'
```

produces

```
Éé
```

as expected.

And so does

```
echo  "\\xC3\\x89\\xC3\\xA9" | iconv -t utf-8
```

Read also [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html).

Notice that some [character encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) (e.g. old plain [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)) don't have any `é` or `É` characters, and others (e.g. [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)) encode them differently.

Comment: When I run `echo  "\\xC3\\x89\\xC3\\xA9" | iconv -t utf-8` my output is the same as the input, same for normal `echo`. `LANG=en_CA.UTF-8` and `LC_ALL` not set. I'm hoping to have something that will work on a variety of machines.

Comment: You can't display `é` on an ASCII system, because that letter does not exist in ASCII encoding.

Answer (score 2):

`iwlist` displays all the bytes that don't correspond to ASCII non-control characters as the `\xHH` where `HH` is the byte number in hexadecimal.

To undo that encoding, you can pipe the output of `iwlist` to

```
perl -pe 's/\\x([\da-f]{2})/chr(hex($1))/gie'
```

Byte `0xc3` followed by `0xa9` make up the UTF-8 encoding of the `é` character.

If your locale also uses the UTF-8 encoding, then the output of `perl` will show that `é` character. If not (unlikely as UTF-8 is the norm), you can always pipe the output of `perl` to `iconv -f utf-8` to convert it `f`rom UTF-8 to the character encoding used in your locale.